# Can't get fancyhdr package to work at all, nothing happens

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Very new to TeX. I'm following a guide by ShareLatex on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZcV1wIPCBo

However when I import the fancyhdr package and define the pagestyle to fancy nothing seems to happen.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\title{
    {`"Title"}\\
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {Research Report}\\
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{lit_logo.png}}\\
    \date{}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\large Bachelor of Science (Honours) null}\\
    \vspace{.5cm}
    {\large null}\\
    \author{null}
    \date{October 2017}
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
    {Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?}
\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction}

\chapter*{Project Aims}
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

\chapter*{Project Objectives}
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are those chapters only one page long so far? The first page of every chapter uses a different style called plain.

Comment: For the titlepage, you might want to take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: Ah! That's the problem. Didn't realise that the first page of every chapter uses plain. I added more lorem ipsum to generate a second page and its working fine now. Thanks!